# Cakephp3 set association id on save

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I currently have a `Products` table, which belongsTo an `Artists` table. I want on the add action of the Products controller to set manually the `artist_id` foreign key of the created product. It gives me a validation error :

Add action:

```
public function add($artist_id)
{
    $artist = $this->Products->Artists->get($artist_id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $product->artist = $artist;
        $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data, [
            'fieldList' => [
                'photo', 'name', 'price', 'reference'
            ]
        ]);
        if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('product', 'artist'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['product']);
}
```

Debug of the entity after the save failed :

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

    'new' => true,
    'accessible' => [],
    'properties' => [
        'artist' => object(App\Model\Entity\Artist) {

            'new' => false,
            'accessible' => [
                'photo' => true,
                'name' => true,
                'interview' => true
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'id' => (int) 5,
                'name' => 'Hello',
                'interview' => 'Hello'
            ],
            'dirty' => [],
            'original' => [],
            'virtual' => [],
            'errors' => [],
            'repository' => 'Artists'

        },
        'photo' => [
            'name' => '10714569_10152447024309147_3742856299050670367_o.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpTtqrXR',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 235835
        ],
        'name' => 'Nataliee',
        'price' => (float) 200000000,
        'reference' => '000'
    ],
    'dirty' => [
        'artist' => true,
        'photo' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'reference' => true
    ],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [
        'artist_id' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ]
    ],
    'repository' => 'Products'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *want* to set the `artist_id` foreign key value, but you actually you *do not* do that, so that's the expected behavior.

What you *are* doing, is setting an entity for the `artist` field, but this won't affect validation/table rules in any way, they are only being applied to the array data passed to the `patchEntity()` call, and in your case they seem to require the `artist_id` field to be present.

So, either set the `artist_id` field in the data, something like

```
$this->request->data['artist_id'] = $artist->id;
$product = $this->Products->patchEntity(/* ... */);
// ...
```

or change your validation/table rules so that for this specific action, the `artist_id` field is not being required, for example by using a different validation set.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Saving Data > Validating Data Before Building Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validating-data-before-building-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > Validation > Validating Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-entities)**

Comment: I tried this too and it gives the same error. And in the documentation, they actually do it this way and it's specified that the foreign key id is set automatically : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations . But I think it's something specific to patchEntity, that requires the field to be present, but I don't know how to get around this properly ?

Comment: @whitep4nther Sorry, my bad, I've mentioned it right in the sentence before the example, but I still didn't pay attention :), of course the field needs to be set in the data that is passed to `patchEntity()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @whitep4nther The foreign key being set automatically happens _after_ validation, in between saving.